# The strange behaviour of the Oracle "insert into" command

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm observing the strange situation in work "insert into" command.
I'll try to explain the situation from my point a view
There is TEMP_LINKS table in my database and application inserts data into it.
Say the query lays in insert1.sql

```
insert into TEMP_LINK (ID, SIDE)
select ID, SIDE 
from //inner query// 
group by ID, SIDE;

commit;
```

and there is java1 class which execute it

```
...
executeSqlScript(getResource("path-to-query1"));
...
```

After that, another java2 class make another insert into the same TEMP_LINK table

```
...
executeSqlScript(getResource("path-to-query2"));
...
```

where query2 looks like

```
insert into TEMP_LINK (ID, SIDE)
select 
ID, 'B'
from (
select ID
from ...tables
where ..conditions
minus (
select ID
from ..tables
union
select ID
from TEMP_LINKS
);

commit;
```

Both java1 and java2 are executed in different threads and java1 is finished earlier that java2.
But time to time, second insert(from query2) don't insert data at all. I see in log: Update count 0 and in TEPM_LINKS there are data only from query1.
If I'm running the application again the issue is disappeared and both of the queries inserted properly data.
Earlier I tried to put both of the queries into one sql file, but the issue has appeared too.
So, maybe someone has ideas about what should I do, because mine is over. One interesting fact - sql "minus" operation is used only once  - in that query2.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by running the scripts manually?

Comment: java1 and java2 are executed in different threats, you say. But one after the other, or they can be executed in parallel ? Keep in mind that the data on java1 will not be visible to java2 until commit.

Comment: When you execute from java - do you handle the exceptions - do you log them to see what is wrong? May be there is `unique` constraint violation or something like that.

Comment: @Lini - nope, the second running give the right result (both queries insert data)

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez - yes they run in the different threads, but first starts java 1 and it finish before java2

Comment: @Pirklee - yes, exceptions are handled and log does not show any exception

Comment: if there is no exception - then the only way not to insert anything - is if the `select` used by the `insert` returns nothing. Are your inner queries affected by the execution of the threads?

Comment: There is not *strange behaviour* if an `insert ... select` produces no rows. You have simple no new `ID` that should be stored and you provided no aggrument why this should be *not* the case. The table `TEMP_LINK(S)` (typo?) is used in query2 in `minus`, so the more `ID`'s are inserted in query1 the less will be processed in query2 - *strange* seems to be therefore your expectation ...

Comment: @Marmite Bomber - the most time all runs good and query2 returns 180 rows, but sometimes it returns 0 that's why it's strange for me. There is one "gray zone" - query2 uses 
```
select .... minus select .... 
```
and inside the second select is used TEMP_LINKS table, which is filled by query1. So maybe it is a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

A big difference between Oracle and SQL Server, Oracle NEVER blocks a read. This is true even when records are locked. The following is a simplified explanation. Oracle uses the System Change Number (SCN) at the time a transaction starts to determine the state of the database for that transaction. All sorts of things can happen, inserts, updates, and deletes, the transaction sees the database as it was at the start of that transaction. Changes only matters at the point where the commit/rollback is executed.

In your situation, if the second query starts before the first has committed, the second won't see any changes the first has made, even after the first commits. You need to synchronize those transactions. The easiest way is to combine them into a single sequential execution. Oracle has many more complex synchronization methods, I would not go that route in this situation.